# Accessing function from a function with the same controller (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs

Quick and easy one.

When I am trying to call a function from another function within the same angular controller. Why I can't get to second function?

Example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.get = function(val1, val2, val3){
        // in reality this is a bit more complex
        // but idea of calling another function within
        // the same controller is the same
        return $scope.getSomething(val1, val2, val3);
    };
    $scope.getSomething = function(val1, val2, val3){
        // return something
        var something = [];
        return something;
    };
}]);
```

It's a bare bone idea but I can't seem to hit that `getSomething` function from `get` function. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I also tried just plain ol' `function getSomething() {...}` with the same controller and still no joy.

Comment: `getSometing` is spelled wrong, missing an `h` - possible typo?

Comment: Don't mind spelling mistakes. It's just an example to get my message across.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*: you're not calling it. What have you tried to call it?

Comment: It seems like you're calling $scope.getResults instead of $scope.getSomething. Was that on purpose?

Comment: OK, I fixed my example. @Carlos.Perea well spotted.

Comment: @JB.Nizet sorry that was my examples mistake.

Comment: Now that you fixed all the mistakes, it should work fine. Just test it.

Comment: The issue still persists for me. Let me see if I can put a fiddler together for this.

Comment: what if you moved $scope.getSomething above the function that is calling it?

Comment: OK, that seem to do the trick. Not sure why when I swap positions it doesn't wok. Probably a silent error in my code somewhere. Back to the drawing board for me.